# Why such uncertain Increment in value?

Tags: c

I was writing this code on codeblocks(only compiler I m having).When I encountered such a behaviour. plz Somebody suggest why is this happening with ct, am I missing something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int lov[3][2]={0};        
    int ct=0;
    char* art;
    if(argc!=4)
        return 1;   


   art=argv[1];
        do
        {
            if(*art=='L' & *(art+1)=='o' & *(art+2)=='c')
            {
                printf("\n\n (art+3)=%s ,*(art+3)=%c ,*(art+5)=%c",(art+3),*(art+3),*(art+5) );
                lov[ct][ct]=*(art+3)-48;
                lov[ct][ct+1]=*(art+5)-48;
                printf("\nct=%d,lov[x][x]=%d,lov[x][x+1]=%d ",ct,lov[ct][ct],lov[ct][ct+1]);
                ct++;
            }
            art+=3;
        }
        while(*(art++));
getchar();
}
```

And on command prompt:-

```
>Resol.exe Loc2,5 Loc3,8 Loc5,4
Output:-


 (art+3)=2,5 ,*(art+3)=2 ,*(art+5)=5
ct=0,lov[x][x]=2,lov[x][x+1]=5

 (art+3)=3,8 ,*(art+3)=3 ,*(art+5)=8
ct=1,lov[x][x]=3,lov[x][x+1]=8

 (art+3)=5,4 ,*(art+3)=5 ,*(art+5)=4
```

> ct=5,lov[x][x]=4198582

,lov[x][x+1]=4

Why ct becomes 5????(last Line)

Comment: Your code accesses `argv` in a very suspect manner. Consider converting to a `for` loop to access `argv`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? To me as a stranger it does make no sense at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that `ct` is being overwritten because you are accessing `lov` out of bounds. Your compiler is probably placing `ct` and `lov` close to each other on the stack which is why `ct` is being modified incorrectly.

When `ct` equals `1` you write to `lov[ct][ct+1]`, which is `lov[1][2]`. That is out of bounds. But the next time round you write to `lov[2][2]` and `lov[2][3]` and one of those will be the one that causes the modification to `ct`.

When you write `lov[ct][ct+1]`, that can only be valid for `ct == 0`. All other values of `ct` result in out-of-bounds access of the array.

I would not be surprised if there are other such errors given the confusing nature of this code.

Comment: Perfect thanks.....seems like stack is overwritten with five....thanks very much

Comment: @sepp2k Even `lov[1][2]` is still out-of-bounds and will result in  behaviour not as intended. And yes, it will be the `lov[2][X]` accesses that modify `ct`, as I already said.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has multiple problems and C does what you say.

---

Before dereferencing pointers like this:

```
if(*art=='L' & *(art+1)=='o' & *(art+2)=='c')
```

you should check whether they are valid at all, i.e. you should first check the length of `art`.

---

Your format string is ill:

```
printf("\n\n (art+3)=%s ,*(art+3)=%c ,*(art+5)=%c",(art+3),*(art+3),*(art+5) );
```

i.e., you are using format specifiers like this:

```
a)    %s <- art+3
b)    %c <- *(art+3)
c)    %c <- *(art+5)
```

a) This potentially tricks `printf` into reading illegal und unintended memory sections -> Undefined behaviour probable.

b) Potentially illegal read -> Undefined behaviour probable.

c) Potentially illegal read -> Undefined behaviour probable.

---

Then,

```
lov[ct][ct]=*(art+3)-48;
lov[ct][ct+1]=*(art+5)-48;
```

Nowhere you put a limit on `ct`, so you are eligible for potential illegal writing -> Undefined behaviour invitation.

---

Then:

```
while(*(art++));
```

What is `art`? Where did you initialize it? Why do you increment it?

---

All in all: You probably doom you `ct` value at the point where you seemingly write to `lov`:

```
lov[ct][ct]=*(art+3)-48;
lov[ct][ct+1]=*(art+5)-48;
```

Comment: Thanks...Next Time I will post 3000 lines of code with all buffer security,heap security,and whatsoever is there....

Comment: @peril brain: Never post fantasy code. Post actual code. The code you've shown is just bad, wrong, and has lots of undefined behaviour. If you would have had the checks and security as well as correct code (which you imply you've just omitted for example's sake), the error would not have arised.

Answer (score 0):

`lov` is an array with dimensions `[3][2]`. `ct` is `5`, so `lov[5][5]` is way out of bounds. No guarantees on what you'll get.

Comment: Problem is why ct is going to 5???